# Converting All Blocks to Lines and Text

Tags: autocad

When I receive a drawing, I wish to remove all definitions from previous drafters, such as blocks, styles, layers, groups, xrefs, etc. in order to retain only primitives: texts, lines and arcs, in summary, a single *flat* drawing.

This is a very routinary activity, and I've found many dissimilar answers through internet, often involving non-standard, non-canonical, combinations of the following commands:

- `LAYMRG`, `PURGE`
- `AUDIT`
- `SELECTSIMILAR`
- `WBLOCK`
- `EXPLODE`, `XPLODE`
- `DIMSTYLE`, `BATTMAN`
- `DXFOUT`, `WMFOUT`, `DXFIN`, `WMFIN`
- `BURST`

Unfortunately, after applying most them, the result sometimes  retain many *non-purgable* objects, including:

- Non-explodable blocks,
- Dimensions with their own styles,
- Blocks losing their text attributes (by `XPLODE`),
- Changed fonts (by `WMFOUT`),

Do AutoCAD have some canonical way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not so easy. If there is such command, I don't know that, but...
In situation You described, You should attach drawing You get as External reference XRef . In that case, You can make such drawing displayed as darker or lighter, but without so many changes in drawing. Also if You get new version of such file, for example because Architect make some changes, You don't need to do anything, maybe only reload such file and new version is displayed.

You will have two separate files:

1. base, for example architecture
2. branch , for example electircal, HVAC, and so on. Your work.

Of corse You can think about some script (scr file of LISP) which will run all commands You want just by run one command. Create such script is not very complicated, but In my opinion it's easy and flexible enought to use XRef.